# Spring AOP - How to get annotation of parent(caller) method

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

```
@Before(value="@annotation(com.aspect.Loggable)",argNames="taskId")

public void logEmail(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

    System.out.println("@Before is running!");
    System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("******");
}
```

i have a pointCut on method `sendEmail()` with custom annotation.

This method `sendEmail()` is called from differnt location in our application .

Like we call sendEmail from `paymentApproved ()` method of paymentManager when payment is approved.
We call sendEmail from `taskComplete()` method of taskManger when task is completed.

i have to find out the event for which sendEmail is triggered.

I applied custom annotation `@EVENT("PAYMENT")` on `paymentApproved ()` of paymentManager and `@EVENT("TASK")` on `taskComplete()` method of taskManger.

How can i get the value of `@EVENT` in `logEmail(JoinPoint joinPoint)` aspect.

Answer (score 4):

**Scaffolding:**

Sorry, I do not like all-caps class names and I also used my own package names as an example because my template already generates them.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Event {
  String value();
}
```

**Driver application:**

This is pure Java because I am not a Spring user. Just imagine it is one or more `@Component`s.

Please also note that in one case `sendEmail()` is called from a method not annotated by `@Event`. This should not trigger the aspect, only the two calls from the annotated methods.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.doSomething();
    application.paymentApproved();
    application.taskComplete();
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    sendEmail();
  }

  @Event("paymentApproved")
  public void paymentApproved() {
    sendEmail();
  }

  @Event("taskComplete")
  public void taskComplete() {
    sendEmail();
  }

  @Loggable
  public void sendEmail() {}
}
```

**Aspect:**

Your pointcut wants to express: Catch methods annotated with `@Loggable` within the control flow of methods annotated by `@Event`. Control flow can be expressed by `cflow()` or `cflowbelow()` pointcuts.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import de.scrum_master.app.Event;

@Aspect
public class LogAspect {
  @Before(
    "@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.Loggable) &&" +
    "execution(* *(..)) &&" +  // only needed for AspectJ, not for Spring AOP
    "cflow(@annotation(event))"
  )
  public void logEmail(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Event event) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + event);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.sendEmail()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Event(value=paymentApproved)
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.sendEmail()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Event(value=taskComplete)
```

---

**Update:** If you were using full AspectJ (e.g. via load-time weaving) instead of Spring AOP, you just could have used a `call()` pointcut and from there get the enclosing joinpoint's static information. Then the `@Event` annotation would not have been necessary. But Spring AOP is just "AOP lite" and does not support `call()`.

Comment: Hi kriegaex thanks for response : This is excat what i need but For "cflow" it gives me error : "unsupported pointcut primitive 'cflow' ".

I search spring does not support this only aspectJ support.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that because I never use Spring AOP. But if you do need `cflow()` you can still decide to use AspectJ LTW from within your Spring application. [This chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) describes how to configure it. As I said: Spring AOP is "AOP lite". ;-) You can also choose @mlg's indirect solution if you want to stick with Spring AOP.

Answer (score -1):

You can access to the annotation receiving it as a parameter. Something like this:

```
@Before(value="@annotation(EVENT)",argNames="taskId")

public void logEmail(JoinPoint joinPoint, Event event) {

    // do what you need with event. For example, if the field is called value you can do this:
    if ("PAYMENT".equals(event.value())) {
       // do sth
    }

    System.out.println("@Before is running!");
    System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("******");
}
```

Comment: That is not the answer to the OP's question. He wants to get the event annotation from the other joinpoint where `sendEmail` is executed.

Comment: If I didnt't understand it wrong, he is using the same annotation in both the methods that call `sendEmail` and the pointcut is for this annotation

Comment: You did understand it wrong, I guess. He wants to still have a pointcut on `sendEmail` and from there access the caller's annotation. I know that changing the pointcut to the caller methods also solves the problem in an indirect way, but what if you annotate a method with an event annotation which never calls the e-mail method but does something else? See my upcoming solution.